# why does grViz plot a different graph each time? How can I freeze it?

Tags: r, diagrammer

I'm using the grViz function from the DiagrammeR package, and I have defined a graph. My problem is that each time I plot it, I get a different arrangement.

for example, you will get a different plot each time you run the codes below.
Is there a way to change this behaviour? (i.e. freeze a graph)

```
 grViz(
  "digraph {

  node [shape=circle, style=filled, fillcolor=skyblue]
  1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10; 11; 12; 13; 14; 15; 16; 17; 18; 19; 20

  1->2; 2->{3 4}; 3->4;
  5->6; 6->7
  8->{9 10 11}; 10->{9 11 12}; 11->12
  13->{14 15}
  16->{17 18 19}; 19->{18 20}
  4->5; 5->8; 11->13; 13->16

  }",engine="neato"
)
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `set.seed` before `grViz`?

Comment: @NickK Yes. doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

it is the same graph in terms of nodes and edges, it is just rotated, the relationships remain the same

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: you're right that the structure is the same, but the relative positions change. This is important to me since I was going to use it for presentation purposes.